# Fee for Transit visa for Ethiopian passport holder

Tags: visas, turkey, ethiopian-citizens

We are Ethiopian passport holders. We are travelling to the USA but have an eight hour stopover in Turkey on the way, we wanted to visit Turkey. Do we need a visa? If so how much is the cost?

Comment: If you want to leave the airport in Turkey you will need to apply for an e-visa

Comment: Here is a link to the Turkish embassy in Addis Ababa http://addisababa.emb.mfa.gov.tr/Mission

Answer (score 6):

To leave the airport you will need an E-Visa. The requirements, FAQ, and application can be found [here](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

You will need to pay a fee of $20 USD (plus a service fee)

If you want to simply stay in the airport then no visa is needed, only an onwards ticket and a valid visa for the country you wish to travel to as stated [here](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa).